# LinQ how to multiplay inside a SUM method

Tags: linq, sum

solved: IstBestellwert = grouped.Sum(o => (double)o.SollMenge * (double)o.Preis) works

My SQL Statment

```
 SELECT        ABId, SUM(Preis * IstMenge) AS IstBestellwert, SUM(Preis * SollMenge) AS SollBestellwert
    FROM            vChainStoreOrderingDetails
    GROUP BY ABId, FilialId
    HAVING  

  (ABId = 10) AND (FilialId IN (8, 140))
```

my try in linq

```
from csod in db.vChainStoreOrderingDetails
                                  where csod.Lieferdatum == lieferdatum && csod.ABId == ab.Id
                                  && filialen.Select(o => o.FilialId).Contains(csod.FilialId)
                                  group csod by new
                                  {
                                      csod.ABId
                                  } into grouped
                                  select new
                                  {
                                     test =grouped.Sum(o=> new {  test =((double) o.Preis * (double)o.SollMenge)})
                                  });
```

but the select part doesnt work. How can i make a multiplication inside the grouped.Sum()
so i sum the multiplikated value

Comment: You may want to put an update at the beginning of the question that you have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IstBestellwert = grouped.Sum(o => (double)o.SollMenge * (double)o.Preis)

okay this seeems to work sry for asking